# Javascript array with image refreshing code

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, list, refresh

Hopefully this is not too complicated.  I have a single line of code used to make an image refresh at a set interval.  This works great.  I can repeat this line of code, and just change the unique name on each, and get multiple images on each page to refresh.  What I would like to do is have a list or array at the top of the page, set the image locations there, and set a title for each image there.  It would make things much simpler than fishing through tons of code trying to cut and paste when changing the images out.

Here's the line of code I use: (refresh1 gets renamed refresh2, refresh3, etc. for each picture)

```
<img src="http://somewhere.com/picture1.jpg" id="refresh1" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refresh1\').src=\'somewhere.com/picture1.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 15000)" />
```

I'd like to do something at the top using a javascript array (or CSS maybe?) to the effect of:

```
Array:    
image1= somewhere.com/picture1.jpg
image2= somewhere.com/picture2.jpg
title1= "Picture of someplace Fun"
title2= "Picture of someplace Hot"
```

And then call them down below in my code by:

```
<display text from 'title1'>
<img src="image1" id="refresh1" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refresh1\').src=\'image1?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 15000)" />

<display text from 'title2'>
<img src="image2" id="refresh2" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refresh2\').src=\'image2?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 15000)" />
```

As you can see, I don't really know much about calling things from a table or array!

Comment: Maybe I should add that each page will have about 20 images.  The img src lines of code are all down in lots of tables and surrounded by other code.  I'd like to set all the img src lines with a set variable (ie: image1 for the image location http:, and title1 for the description of the image) and then never have to scroll down and find or alter them.  At the top of the page, a list/array of the image=http logation, and title=description.  From all the searching I've done, I'm thinking this isn't possible, especially not when using the code I have in each img src that refreshes that image

Answer (score 1):

I would use selectors to get your images and then insert the values from your variables.

```
document.getElementById("refresh1").src = image1
document.getElementById("refresh2").src = image2
```

`image1` and `image2` will need to be string values as well.

EDIT: Replaced jQuery with DOM instructions

Comment: Not too sure how to implement that.  I'm trying to read a tutorial on jquery now... maybe I can figure out how to use what you posted.  What about something to call the text description 'title' to go along with each image?  
Is this variable code for both images and title description something that can be done in the html page, and be different on each page?  Because I need each website page to be unique, it probably wouldn't work to have to make and upload a file that has the variables in it.

Comment: Apologies, should have realized you were probably more familiar with proper DOM instructions instead of jQuery. I recommend learning it though, it will make life a little easier.

But for the titles, just include `div` or `span` elements with corresponding ids that will allow you to inject the `title` vars into them.